# finding x and y coordinates of black Squares - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of licence plate and the numbers is marked with black squares.
what I want is to get all the coordinates of the squares, and with it to cut them from the plate.

for example this is the original image:

[image]

and this is after marking the numbers:

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Mr E I have the two images. first I marked each digit in the plate with square and then I want to cut with the square details the numbers from the plate. alternatively, if you have some way to cut the numbers from the plate without mark them first it will be good also. but I need universal way that fit for every plate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in Matlab

```
%# read the first image
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9A4m.jpg');
%# convert it to a binary image
img = rgb2gray(img);
img = img > 200;
%# remove the connecting lines
img = imclose(img,strel('disk',5));
%# use bwlabel to replace the black squares with a index (1,2,3...)
lblImg = bwlabel(~img);

%# read the second image, make it binary
img2 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtKzw.jpg');
img2 = img2 > 200;

%# create the output - each number is now labeled with an index
out = double(~img2).*lblImg;

%# visualize all
figure,imshow(label2rgb(out,'jet','k','shuffle'))
```

[image]

```
%# extract and show label #1
firstNumber = out==1;
imshow(firstNumber);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your great answer. is there a way to show only the digit instead of showing all the black background? another question, is there a way to know if what labeled is indeed digit?

Comment: @Michael: To show only the digit, you can write `imshow(~firstNumber)` in the last line. To find out whether you have a digit, you should have a look at OCR methods.

Comment: thanks again. I want to cut only the digit, without the background, because later I use it in a correlation function. is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Michael: So you just want to get rid of all the area where there is only background, right? For this, you can write `[r,c]=find(firstNumber)`;croppedNumber = firstNumber(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c:));`

Answer (score 1):

I don't do Matlab, but I can show you how to do it in Mathematica. Hopefully you can translate!

[image]

Comment: that is very impressive.. I had no idea mathematica could do these kinds of things.

Comment: @zephyr The image processing capabilities of Mathematica got much better in the last two releases. It's now a very nice testbed for algorithms. Perhaps the performance is not good enough for production, but you can do things like the above program in five minutes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the image processing toolbox.

The functions bwdist, imregionalmin and bwselect should be able to get you the square coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch answer as I'm in a rush. You have some white dots in the squares and some black streaks connecting the squares. Look up the morphological operations such as:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imclose.html

Close the image with a small structuring element (3x3 square or similar) to get rid of the bits of noise in the squares.

Open the image with a larger structuring element (10x10 square or bigger) get rid of the connecting streaky bits.

Then use a function like bwlabel to segment/label the remaining pixels. This is a little imprecise as the squares will lose some of the structure at the edges.